# Python based Raspberry pi with PHP web client - Better solution

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, urllib

I have a problem, but first, let me explain the story:

My "Weekend-Project" was to build a Remote control between my Raspberry Pi and our school's website, which is a simple system - since it was only a 2days project - what can execute python scripts on the pi (written on the site) && control the PiFace's outputs attached to my Raspberry. Like a small "automated-home" system.

I tried to make the site the least designed, since it's not important. Take a look at it:
[image]

It's working, and my teacher who suggested the project found it very interesting, but here comes my problem:

I used Python's urllib library to open a certain url, read data from it, handle them & communicate with it.
But, I don't like it, because it has to open the url every secound to be effective >> very high bandwidth usage & requests...

I need a better solution for this.
Since PHP can handle sockets, shall I try communicating with those instead?

Any suggestion or idea would be nice. Thanks!